# How to reduce this If block to one statement?

Tags: ruby

```
    if firstcheck? || secondcheck?
      nil
    else
      true
    end
```

How can i reduce this block of code to one single line? 
If the condition is correct i need to return nil, else true

Please help

Comment: Use ternary operator, you can chain them if there are more conditions to check for.

Comment: When asking, we expect to see evidence of your effort. Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Comment: I already wrote a bunch of code. But this is just a small case, so I thought why to create confusion by adding unnecceary data too.Sorry if i done anything wrong

Comment: Clearly this question is not a duplicate of "How do I use the conditional operator?" since you can give a good answer to it that doesn't involve the conditional operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is equivalent to the snippet of code you wrote:

```
true unless firstcheck? || secondcheck?
```

I have to wonder if you really have a requirement to return `nil` instead of `false`.  If you are OK with returning `false` instead of `nil`, you could write it as:

```
!firstcheck? && !secondcheck?
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to return nil instead of false.How does the first statement return nil?

Comment: I'd use `!(firstcheck? || secondcheck?)` instead of `!firstcheck? && !secondcheck?`

Comment: norman bates:  That's just how Ruby works.  `... unless true` always evaluates to `nil` since it has to have some value.  Similarly, `... if false` always evaluates to `nil`.

Comment: I think `firstcheck? || secondcheck? ? nil : true` reads best. If characters are precious, you could write `!(firstcheck? || secondcheck?) || nil`. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯